# Multiple template classes in assembly have the same TcmTemplateTitle attribute - TcmUploadAssembly.exe

Tags: web8, templating, tom.net

I'm getting below error while uploading the .NET Assembly into "Tridion".

**Error: Multiple template classes in assembly have the same TcmTemplateTitle attribute**

1. I tried to rename the "TcmTemplateTitle" for the conflicting classes
   and after building the solution, tried to upload the dll into tridion.
2. Tried to exclude the conflicting classes from the project and after 
   successful build, tried to upload the dll into tridion.

None of the above resolve the issue, still I'm getting the same error.

**Question:** Does Tridion stores the references of the .NET Assembly & its TcmTemplateTitle attributes? I did clean, rebuild the solution, dlls are generating with the correct time stamp. But while uploading its throwing the same error.

Could you please let me know if anyone faced this kind of issue and how to fix this.

Comment: Do you get the same error when uploading the DLL into a separate folder with NO TBBs present in it ? Try that and see what happens

Comment: Possibly check for derived classes in your assembly too. May be some parent class is having the same [TcmTemplateTitle]

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a .NET Assembly into Tridion (at least in 2011!), you specify a target folder, e.g. `TcmUploadAssembly /folder:tcm:14-60-2 MyConfig.xml MyDll.dll`

If you look in that folder, in our case, tcm:14-60-2, then you'll see the DLL `MyDll` stored as a .NET Assembly, and a load of other TBBs stored as C# Code Fragments.

The other TBBs are references to the classes in your dll.  The title is taken from the `[TcmTemplateTitle]` attribute or the class name, and they are essentially instructions to run a specific class in your dll.

Since these are not deleted on upload, I suspect this is just a name conflict.  I think you can probably resolve by deleting or renaming the TBBs in the target folder.  If none of the items are in use, you can probably just wipe the contents of the folder and re-upload.  If they are in use, then you will need to be a little more careful to avoid duplicate TBBs and any additional confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. I tried renaming the conflicting TBBs and while uploading the assembly, still its throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uploading the assembly in to a different, empty, folder?